# JQuery Issue with Same page login

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

ok, odd behaviour in **IE 9** and **JQuery**.

I have the following WebConfig settings:

```
   <authentication mode="Forms" >
    <forms loginUrl="Default.aspx"
      name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"  />
    </authentication>
```

Basically, I am using a single page to login and present the main infomration of my site. The page loads and then checks if the user is logged in. If not then a panel called `pnlNotLoggedIn` is made visible, and a respective `pnlLoggedIn` is made invisible.

My problem is as follows:

First time around, the `Default.aspx` page, loads the respective JQuery resources, but then, due to the nature of my page, the page is loaded again, but this time with a URL redirect, which fires off loading the respective Jquery files again.

Visual Studio throws an error that

> $ is undefined.

However, this doesn't happen in Firefox or chrome, so I think there must be an issue with **IE9**.

The screen shot, shows the network traffic, i've jsut tried to explain.

**My question is, how can i prevent this from happening. Can I load the .js files within my Page_Load method after I've authenticated the user?**

Comment: you can add the js files into your masterpage and so they are usable every time

Comment: Yeah, sorry - i dont have enough points to post a pic. It's not a issue about where they are declared. Effectively, becuase the same page is being redrawn, i'm getting functions trying to load before the page has finished doing what it needs to do.

Comment: ok, this link helped to answer my own question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614747/single-page-login